# Paypal Billing Agreement approval_url using sdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angularjs, paypal-sandbox

Billing agreement Paypal payment method, while we are calling order api backend initiating the order from Paypal and in response on frontend we are getting the approval_url to complete the paypal payment, so my question:

1. can we use sdk(braintree or paypal) to open approval_url in the popup?

a quick response will be highly appreciated thank you.

I have tried with window.location(approval_url,'_blank');
can we use any sdk to just hit the popup window with the approval_url?

Comment: The solution is to use the JS SDK, but the specifics of how to use it will depend on the request/response parameters of the order you are creating and what exactly you mean by "billing agreement". Add such detail to the question.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: on frontend just getting the paypal payment approval_url from the api , can we use sdk to open it in popup window

Comment: If you want to open the URL in a popup instead of redirecting the current window to it - then don't assign it to `window.location`, but make a `window.open` call instead ...? (But if there is no _direct_ connection to a user action, this is likely to get blocked by popup blockers.)

Comment: can we integrate using paypal/javascript sdk to open a (paypal) popup passing approval_url token?